# Enumerating subsets with no triple appearing together more than once

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics, steiner-triple-system

This question is motivated by a real-world application related to an art project that involves displaying images, but my search hit a dead end after finding the wikipage about [**Kirkman systems**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirkman%27s_schoolgirl_problem) (other related terms include [**Steiner systems**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_system) and the [**Social golfer problem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_golfer_problem)) and looking over references linked there. A few people have written programs for this specific question that established lower bounds (so: more than $2100$) but none has found an exact answer.

**The question is:**

> Given a set of $40$ elements, what is the maximum number of subsets, each with $4$ elements, that can be created such that no triple appears more than once?

(For example, if the set includes $A,B,C,D,E$ as elements, then one cannot include in the collection of subsets *both* $\{A,B,C,D\}$ *and* $\{A,B,C,E\}$ since, in this scenario, we would have the triple $A,B,C$ appearing more than once.)

As an excerpt from the [**History**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirkman%27s_schoolgirl_problem#History) section of the aforelinked wikipage, there is under the first bullet point a question attributed to Wesley Woolhouse (1844):

> "Determine the number of combinations that can be made out of $n$ symbols, $p$ symbols in each; with this limitation, that no combination of $q$ symbols, which may appear in any one of them shall be repeated in any other."

followed by the formula:

$$\frac{n!}{q!(n-q)!)} \div \frac{p!}{q!(p-q)!}$$

Unfortunately, one finds that this formula is *false* already for small examples (e.g. $n=5, p=4, q=3$) and, indeed, reading further on that page indicates that the formula only holds in certain scenarios.

Rephrased, I am looking for an answer to Woolhouse's question for the case of $n=40, p=4, q=3$ either by a counting argument, an effective program, or a reference. Please tag/retag as appropriate; thanks!

Comment: Is it correct to rephrase this question as:  What is the maximum size of a family $\mathcal F \subseteq \binom{\mathbf n}p$ (writing $\binom{\mathbf n}p$ for the set of $p$-element subsets of an $n$-element set $\mathbf n$) such that $\lvert A \cap B\rvert$ is strictly less than $q$ for all $A, B \in \mathcal F$?

Comment: You write "Given a set of 40 elements, what is the maximum number of subsets that can be created such that no triple appears more than once?" Given the context in the rest of the question, do I gather correctly that you meant to include the additional condition that each subset has $4$ elements?

Comment: As a lower bound, $\{ \{ a,b,c,d \} : a+b+c+d \equiv 2 \bmod 40 \}$ has 2290 elements, and clearly has no two elements which overlap in size three; this is not too far from the ratio of binomial coefficients, which gives 2470.

Comment: Another way to rephrase this problem is that you are looking for the largest anticlique in the Johnson graph $J(40,4)$. Wikipedia tells me that determining the chromatic number of Johnson graphs is open, which makes me suspect the situation for anticliques will be just as bad. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson_graph

Comment: thanks for the comments & yes @DavidESpeyer I've edited to include the condition that each subset has $4$ elements; RE: $J(40,4)$ I'm not sure whether this means the problem at hand, in particular, may be intractable; also, if that means another tag should be added e.g. around graph theory, then by all means! (The steiner-triple-system one could go if multiple tags are worth adding...)

Comment: @LSpice I had initially omitted the condition that each subset should have size $4$

Comment: Using $\mathbb{Z}/5 \mathbb{Z} \times (\mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z})^3$ instead of the cyclic group of order $40$ improves the lower bound to 2318 (now achieved at the zero element).

Comment: @DavidESpeyer what is meant by "now achieved at the zero element" in your latter comment? (also, in your earlier comment... what motivated the choice of 2 as the remainder, in particular? + did you enumerate the 2290 by program or count by hand?) thanks!

Comment: By computer. I had Mathematica add up all 4-tuples of distinct elements in the abelian group I listed and count which sum was most frequent; the most frequent was the zero element of the group,  which occurred 2318 times. (I hope there are no errors.)

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you tell us more about the real-world application?

Comment: @LouisD It was asked on behalf of an artist; the formulation of the question as it came to me (which essentially contains all the background information that I have) can be found here: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/FLh0W2-X0AAFcxr?format=jpg&name=large

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In fact, Wikipedia article on [Steiner systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_system) that you linked already provides an answer to your question:

> An $S(3,4,n)$ is called a **Steiner quadruple system**. A necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of an $S(3,4,n)$ is that $n \equiv  2\ \text{or}\ 4 \pmod6$.

Notice that $40\equiv 4\pmod{6}$, and so Steiner system $S(3,4,40)$ does exist. It is formed by $\frac{\tbinom{40}{3}}{\tbinom43} = 2470$ blocks (quadruples) that contain every triple *exactly* once.

Actual blocks of such a system can be seen in the La Jolla Covering Repository at [this link](https://ljcr.dmgordon.org/show_cover.php?v=40&k=4&t=3).

Comment: wow, sorry to have missed this! saw the condition on the Kirkman page with $n \equiv 3 \text{mod } 6$ but failed to see it would work in this case. thanks!